# How to pass data from a service to an activity at a high frequency

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

In my Android app I have a `Service` that monitors the file changes of my phone, when there is a new file downloaded, such as an apk file(I use a recursively implemented `FileObserver` class to do the monitor), the `Service` triggers an `Activity`(in the same app), and send the file path of the apk file to the `Activity`.
The problem is that if the user **downloads a lot of apk files at a time**, there maybe a lot of file paths, and  the fequency of a user to download apk files maybe high, I wonder what can I or what method can I use to pass the file paths?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to favour Otto in these situations: http://square.github.io/otto/

From the service you could have...

```
myBus.post(new DownloadEvent());
```

And the Activity can simply have a method...

```
@Subscribe
public void onDownload(DownloadEvent event)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

If the frequency is **VERY** high, you could maintain a pool of DownloadEvent objects and reuse them when posting to the bus to avoid excessive garbage collection.